# OSMnx - Unbelievable speed_kph value in highway

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

Using Python osmnx package to work with OpenStreetMaps, I have created the following bounding box in Madrid, Spain:

```
north, south, east, west = 40.45, 40.40, -3.691, -3.74

# create network from that bounding box
H = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type="drive_service")
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(H, node_size=0, edge_color="w", edge_linewidth=0.2)
```

After imputing speeds and travel times on all edges:

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox

H = ox.speed.add_edge_speeds(H)
H = ox.speed.add_edge_travel_times(H)
```

I have checked some parameters by road type, in the same way as explained in the corresponding [example notebook 02](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/02-routing-speed-time.ipynb):

```
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(H, nodes=False)
edges["highway"] = edges["highway"].astype(str)
edges.groupby("highway")[["length", "speed_kph", "travel_time"]].mean().round(1)
```

However, I have got a value of **561.5 in speed_kph** for primary highways. As far as I understand, this is not correct, so I would need a way of forcing a replace to this value, since the following code is not working:

```
H = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type="drive_service")
hwy_speeds = {"primary": 50}
H = ox.add_edge_speeds(H, hwy_speeds)
H = ox.add_edge_travel_times(H)
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(H, nodes=False)
edges["highway"] = edges["highway"].astype(str)
edges.groupby("highway")[["length", "speed_kph", "travel_time"]].mean().round(1)
```

Is it possible to "force" a fix on the speed_kph value?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can tell OSMnx what speeds to use if you pass the `hwy_speeds` argument, as described in [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.speed).

> By default, this imputes free-flow travel speeds for all edges via the mean maxspeed value of the edges of each highway type. For highway types in the graph that have no maxspeed value on any edge, it assigns the mean of all maxspeed values in graph.
>
> This default mean-imputation can obviously be imprecise, and the user can override it by passing in hwy_speeds and/or fallback arguments that correspond to local speed limit standards. The user can also specify a different aggregation function (such as the median) to impute missing values from the observed values.
>
> If edge maxspeed attribute has “mph” in it, value will automatically be converted from miles per hour to km per hour. Any other speed units should be manually converted to km per hour prior to running this function, otherwise there could be unexpected results. If “mph” does not appear in the edge’s maxspeed attribute string, then function assumes kph, per OSM guidelines: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features/Units

Comment: Your help is really appreciated. However, for some reason even after overriding the values (as in the example) I only get a high speed kph value for "primary" edges:  

```H = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type="drive_service")
hwy_speeds = {"primary": 10, "residential": 20, "unclassified": 30, "maxspeed": 50 }

# impute speed on all edges missing data
H = ox.speed.add_edge_speeds(H, hwy_speeds = hwy_speeds, fallback = 50)

# primary highways present 456.1 kph.
```

Comment: Actually my problem is that I suspect this is affecting the calculation of routes between two points. Following the instructions on the notebooks:

```origH = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(H, X=-3.730481,  Y=40.441382)
destH = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(H, X=-3.6935759, Y=40.4105168)

# (length criteria)  Route 1 is 5271 meters and takes 427 seconds.
# (travel_time criteria) Route 2 is 6939 meters and takes 372 seconds.
```
Which is certainly not possible since Google Maps predicts around 20 min by car.